# Uniform distribution of monthly budget to date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have monthly budget need to distribute to per day

Datasource

| Month | Budget |
| --- | --- |
| Jan | 31 |
| Feb | 56 |

I want to smoothen out to

| Date | Budget |
| --- | --- |
| 01-Jan | 1 |
| 02-Jan | 1 |
| ... | ... |
| 01-Feb | 2 |
| 02-Feb | 2 |
| ... | ... |

How can I do this?

Comment: Is there any cases that the `Budget` is not able to distribute evenly to each of the day in a month ? How do you want to handle this ? Please include such scenario sample data and expected result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the month is really a date on the first day, then a pretty simply method uses a recursive CTE:

```
with cte as (
      select month as day, budget
      from t
      union all
      select dateadd(day, 1, day), budget
      from cte
      where day < eomonth(day)
     )
select day, budget * 1.0 / day(eomonth(day))
from cte
order by day;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=67fb3ce60c4e3aaa21b09a787e317278) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thank you! glad I get to learn the CTE trick

Answer (score 1):

Just another option using an ad-hoc tally/numbers table

This assumes the source `MONTH` is a string and the desired year is the current year.

**Example or [dbFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=02e2f5e00cddbb5c84ac79e073d78605)**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([Month] varchar(50),[Budget] money)
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('Jan',31)
,('Feb',56)
 
Select Date   = DateFromParts(year(D),month(D),N)
      ,Budget = Budget / day(D)
 From @YourTable A
 Cross Apply ( values (EOMonth(try_convert(date,concat('01-',Month,'-',year(getdate())))))) B(D)
 Join (Select Top 31 N=Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select Null)) From  master..spt_values n1) C
   on  N<=day(D)
```

**Results**

```
Date        Budget
2021-01-01  1.00
2021-01-02  1.00
...
2021-01-30  1.00
2021-01-31  1.00
2021-02-01  2.00
...
2021-02-27  2.00
2021-02-28  2.00
```